# 'Dockerizing' Python Tkinter GUI: doesn't display anything but runs fine

Tags: python, docker, tkinter

First day trying to 'Dockerize' my Python GUI made in Tkinter for the purpose of having it as a standalone application and nothing is displayed despite using a recommended command to do so: `run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY background-revolution` (with it supposedly being interactive mode and -e to set the display as the user's own) Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD main.py . 

RUN pip install pillow 

CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

The output it gives me is a test print statement I wrote that says "docker working" but none of the actual GUI (which works fine from running it normally). To build the Docker image this is what I ran: `docker build -t background-revolution .`

```
[+] Building 10.5s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 133B                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.2s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                                                                                                               0.9s 
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:acb4e43d0c66c168e72ceaba5913cde472e4a17017cec9346969c9725a1fea94                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 12.01kB                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [2/3] ADD main.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.5s 
 => [3/3] RUN pip install pillow                                                                                                                                                                                            6.9s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.5s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     1.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:95e56740a3427899906e9c6522198f5d749fd13870450b046a2bd874b3a04548                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/background-revolution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers does't allow GUI, there are some workarounds like redirect to you X server on Unix but it's not a good solution.

If you want a standalone python application, you could use pyinstaller [link](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) or something similar.